# RegExp name validation using hexadecimal metacharacters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make a regex validation using hexadecimal metacharacters. the reason i decided to go this way it because i need only the greek language to work.

from http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/Blocks.txt i see that i need to use characters from 1F00 to 1FFF. however i cannot find what is going wrong.

here's what i've done so far:

```
document.querySelector("#register input[name='first_name']").onblur = 

function(){
    /*RegEx about name*/    
    var str = /[\u1F00-\u1FFF]/g;
    var name = document.querySelector("#registerinput[name='first_name']").value;
    if (name == null || name == ""){
        alert("First name must be filled out!");
    }
    else if(!name.match(str)){
        alert("Name must contain (greek)letters only!");
    }
};
```

Comment: What is not working? And what is the expected behavior?

Comment: It's probably not related to your exact problem, but your regexp will match any single Greek character. It needs to be `/^[\u1F00-\u1FFF]*$/`,

Comment: Well english letters numbers and special chars are not accepted.the problem is that greek chars are also not accepted.
By the way was the down-vote so necessary??????????????????

Comment: That's really... wrong. There's no need to access the same element again via DOM query in its own event handler. Finally, to _test_ a string against a regex use .test(), not `.match()`.

Comment: torazaburo i tried var str = /^[\u1F00-\u1FFF]*$/ but still greek chars are not accepted...

Comment: Ah, just noticed: what's the HTML structure? Do you have an input with id `registerinput`, or it's a child element of `#register`? There's an inconsistency in two queries in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range you are using is Greek extended. You want the range from 0370 to 03ff. From the page you quoted:

> 0370..03FF; Greek and Coptic
>
> 1F00..1FFF; Greek Extended

```
function is_greek(name){
    var greek = /[\u0370-\u03ff]/;
    return greek.test(name);
}

> is_greek("α")
< true
```

Comment: indeed i needed greek and coptic instead greek extended and it works